# Change font in app that uses renderManager in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I use this code in the [Bouncing Spheres](https://github.com/rubo77/Bouncing-Spheres/blob/master/app/src/main/java/istia/ei4/ProjetISTIA/GridGameScreen.java#L195) App, that I want to adapt (I am new in Android development and still working into the code right now) :

```
renderManager.setTextSize(20);
renderManager.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, "example");
```

How do I change the font-family?

I would like to add a digital-clock-style font to the output of the time there.

Answer (score 0):

The RenderManager is a class defined in `/app/src/main/java/istia/ei4/ProjetISTIA/RenderManager.java`

You have to add a second variation of the `DrawText` function that supports font:

```
public void drawText(int x, int y, String str, String font){
    Typeface oldfont=this.brush.getTypeface();
    this.brush.setTypeface(Typeface.create(font,oldfont.getStyle()));
    this.target.drawText(str, x, y, this.brush);
    this.brush.setTypeface(oldfont);
}
```

If you dont want a default font, you can add a custom font like described here: https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/user-interface-basics-637d41b1-35dc-400a-bcc3-65794760474d/adding-custom-fonts